# failed to start program using command line due to "Class not register"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, ultidev, ultidev-cassini

This error occurred when i try to launched my web service on ultidev webserver. can anyone tell me why this error occurred? please help me

```
failed to start program using command line due to Class not Register
```

Comment: so sorry i dont knw what is the answer otherwise i must help you